# What is the best way to do tens of contains & split & replace in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, string

For the following strings

```
id1;#name1;#id2;#name2;#id3;#name3;#id4;#name4
```

which represents a series of ID and Names separated by ";#".
What is best and more optimized way to retrieve the following string,

```
name1, name2, name3, name4
```

which includes names only seperated by ", ".
I'm looking for the most optimized way, as this string may repeated tens of times in page.

Comment: you are demanding on solution??? just kidding.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must do a mixture between jquery and jscript itself. Something like $("tag").name(), something like, supposing that "names" are all the same tag for everyone. You have to save that information in an array (String[] type), and then that array += every_result + ", " + next_result....

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do a split on this tring

```
var test="id1;#name1;#id2;#name2;#id3;#name3;#id4;#name4"
var temp=test.split(';#')
```

now you have all the values in the array

```
var finalstring
for(var i in temp)
{
   if(temp[i].indexOf('name')>0){
   finalstring+=finalstring+temp[i] + ","
   }
}
```

remove comma at the end

```
finalstring=finalstring.substring(0,finalstring.length-1)
```

Comment: You are missing quotes in the first line. And to join the array why don't you use `.join()`...?

Comment: @Rotora , i am not using array , finalstring i am just using string concatination

Comment: For temp[i].indexOf('name')>0, this will not work as name is dynamic value.

Comment: @ahmed you mean name is dyname in your example , then we can change the logic to skip all ids // is your exactly the way you mentioned in the example otherwise how can we differentiate between id and name

Comment: You are using an array: `temp`. BTW, you shouldn't be using `for ... in` on an array. It's doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: @kobe, yes we need to escape ID and ";#" and just retrieve the names only.